# Workaround for dependency on a package with a dash in its name

Tags: setuptools

In one of my setuptools-based Python projects I would like to add a dependency to [`numpy-stl`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy-stl/). That package is on PyPI and depends on [`numpy`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy/). Due to [a bug](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/381), setuptools is unable to install packages with dashes in their names in some circumstances.

This is a minimal `setup.py` which reproduces the problem:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    install_requires=['numpy-stl'])
```

Running `python setup.py develop` produces the following output:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing UNKNOWN.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to UNKNOWN.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to UNKNOWN.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to UNKNOWN.egg-info/requires.txt
reading manifest file 'UNKNOWN.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'UNKNOWN.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
warning: install_lib: 'build/lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install

creating build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying UNKNOWN.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying UNKNOWN.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying UNKNOWN.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying UNKNOWN.egg-info/requires.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying UNKNOWN.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist/UNKNOWN-0.0.0-py3.5.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing UNKNOWN-0.0.0-py3.5.egg
Copying UNKNOWN-0.0.0-py3.5.egg to /Users/michi/Desktop/STL_Plot/stl_plot/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Adding UNKNOWN 0.0.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /Users/michi/Desktop/STL_Plot/stl_plot/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/UNKNOWN-0.0.0-py3.5.egg
Processing dependencies for UNKNOWN==0.0.0
Searching for numpy-stl
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy-stl/

[... installing numpy-stl and some of its dependencies ...]

Installed /Users/michi/Desktop/STL_Plot/stl_plot/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nine-0.3.4-py3.5.egg
Searching for numpy
Best match: numpy stl-1.7.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy-stl/numpy-stl-1.7.1.tar.gz#md5=fa3a9324418b72a6827f266671198fe1
Processing numpy-stl-1.7.1.tar.gz
Writing /var/folders/r3/lpx2z49s5hs8mmh3vzrgxd9c0000gs/T/easy_install-yvi_spnk/numpy-stl-1.7.1/setup.cfg
Running numpy-stl-1.7.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/r3/lpx2z49s5hs8mmh3vzrgxd9c0000gs/T/easy_install-yvi_spnk/numpy-stl-1.7.1/egg-dist-tmp-72gff1lq
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/stl2/stl.py", line 41
     except RuntimeError, (recoverable, e):
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
tests.__pycache__.test_convert.cpython-35: module references __file__
removing '/Users/michi/Desktop/STL_Plot/stl_plot/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy_stl-1.7.1-py3.5.egg' (and everything under it)
creating /Users/michi/Desktop/STL_Plot/stl_plot/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy_stl-1.7.1-py3.5.egg
Extracting numpy_stl-1.7.1-py3.5.egg to /Users/michi/Desktop/STL_Plot/stl_plot/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
  File "/Users/michi/Desktop/STL_Plot/stl_plot/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy_stl-1.7.1-py3.5.egg/stl2/stl.py", line 41
     except RuntimeError, (recoverable, e):
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

numpy-stl 1.7.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing stl2ascii script to /Users/michi/Desktop/STL_Plot/stl_plot/venv/bin
Installing stl2bin script to /Users/michi/Desktop/STL_Plot/stl_plot/venv/bin
Installing stl script to /Users/michi/Desktop/STL_Plot/stl_plot/venv/bin

Installed /Users/michi/Desktop/STL_Plot/stl_plot/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy_stl-1.7.1-py3.5.egg
error: The 'numpy' distribution was not found and is required by numpy-stl
(venv)michi ~/.../STL_Plot/stl_plot$
```

After installing `nine`, setuptools tries to find a `numpy` distribution and finds `numpy-stl`, thinking its the package `numpy` in version `stl` and installs `numpy-stl` again. In the end it detects that `numpy` is still not installed and gives up.

Is this just the way it is, that setuptools projects cannot depend on packages with dashes in their names, which is about 1/4 of the packages on PyPI? Or is there a workaround which allows setuptools to install such dependencies?